# htaccess and wordpress conflict

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a problem with my site because it seems to have too many redirects.

For example, if I open my website with google chrome, I receive this error:

```
"Errore 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)"
```

Following is my htaccess:

---

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/css .css
  AddType text/x-component .htc
  AddType application/x-javascript .js
  AddType application/javascript .js2
  AddType text/javascript .js3
  AddType text/x-js .js4
  AddType text/html .html .htm
  AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
  AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
  AddType text/plain .txt
  AddType text/xsd .xsd
  AddType text/xsl .xsl
  AddType text/xml .xml
  AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
  AddType video/avi .avi
  AddType image/bmp .bmp
  AddType application/java .class
  AddType video/divx .divx
  AddType application/msword .doc .docx
  AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
  AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
  AddType image/gif .gif
  AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
  AddType image/x-icon .ico
  AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
  AddType application/json .json
  AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
  AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
  AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
  AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
  AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
  AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
  AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
  AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
  AddType audio/ogg .ogg
  AddType application/pdf .pdf
  AddType image/png .png
  AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
  AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
  AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
  AddType application/x-tar .tar
  AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
  AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
  AddType audio/wav .wav
  AddType audio/wma .wma
  AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
  AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
  AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
  ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
  ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
  ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
  ExpiresByType text/html A3600
  ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
  ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
  ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
  ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
  ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
  ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
  ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
  ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
  ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
  ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
  ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
  ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
  </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
  FileETag MTime Size
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
  FileETag MTime Size
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
  FileETag MTime Size
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2\.0\ mmp|240x320|alcatel|amoi|asus|au\-mic|audiovox|avantgo|benq|bird|blackberry|blazer|cdm|cellphone|danger|ddipocket|docomo|dopod|elaine/3\.0|ericsson|eudoraweb|fly|haier|hiptop|hp\.ipaq|htc|huawei|i\-mobile|iemobile|j\-phone|kddi|konka|kwc|kyocera/wx310k|lenovo|lg|lg/u990|lge\ vx|midp|midp\-2\.0|mmef20|mmp|mobilephone|mot\-v|motorola|netfront|newgen|newt|nintendo\ ds|nintendo\ wii|nitro|nokia|novarra|o2|openweb|opera\ mobi|opera\.mobi|palm|panasonic|pantech|pdxgw|pg|philips|phone|playstation\ portable|portalmmm|ppc|proxinet|psp|pt|qtek|sagem|samsung|sanyo|sch|sec|sendo|sgh|sharp|sharp\-tq\-gx10|sie|small|smartphone|softbank|sonyericsson|sph|symbian|symbian\ os|symbianos|toshiba|treo|ts21i\-10|up\.browser|up\.link|uts|vertu|vodafone|wap|willcome|windows\ ce|windows\.ce|winwap|xda|zte) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_low]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (acer\ s100|android|archos5|blackberry9500|blackberry9530|blackberry9550|cupcake|docomo\ ht\-03a|dream|htc\ hero|htc\ magic|htc_dream|htc_magic|incognito|ipad|iphone|ipod|lg\-gw620|liquid\ build|maemo|mot\-mb200|mot\-mb300|nexus\ one|opera\ mini|samsung\-s8000|series60.*webkit|series60/5\.0|sonyericssone10|sonyericssonu20|sonyericssonx10|t\-mobile\ mytouch\ 3g|t\-mobile\ opal|tattoo|webmate|webos) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_UA:_high]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_referrer=.*(google\.com|yahoo\.com|bing\.com|ask\.com|msn\.com) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_REF:_search_engines]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
  RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(bot|ia_archive|slurp|crawl|spider) [NC]
  RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_REF}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
  RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_UA}%{ENV:W3TC_REF}%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and cookies and, bizarrely, check the date is correct on your PC. These 2 are the biggest causes of that issue it seems.